# Golang local import via github.com repo doesn't work even though the files are there

Tags: go, package

I do understand Go is quirky for imports, but I've tried following the convention (I believe) to the point, however I cannot import a struct.

Project structure:

```
/project-name
    /parser/main.go
    /query/main.go
... Project files in root
```

I have a struct in `/parser/main.go` exported:

```
package parser
type SomeTranslationStuff struct {
    ID                  int    `json:"Id"`
    Language            string `json:"Language"`
}
```

I wish to import this in `/query/main.go`.

I do it as such:

```
import (
    "github.com/org/project-name/parser"
)
```

It does not import it - I am met with "cannot find package ... in Gopath".

My project exists under: `Users\user\go\src\project-name`. The imported project(which is the same project, imported from github via go get) does indeed exist in `Users\user\go\src\github.com\org\project-name`.. Everything seems according to the "Go"-way of importing stuff, yet it doesn't appear to import?

It specifically says:

```
Cannot find package name:
C:\Users\user\go\src\github.com\org\project-name\parser(from $GOPATH)
```

If I go to that path, the project is, correctly, there! What gives? Why doesn't it import?

Comment: @Flimzy Reading go docs, one should never really import with relative paths. Maybe I am wrong? It's the answer I see most places, like on SO, too. Besides, I've seen other projects with a similar structure as to what I'm attempting here. Id

Comment: You say your code lives in `Users\user\go\src\project-name`. So you should import it as `project-name`.  If you import it as `github.com/org/project-name`, then, as you can tell from the errors, it looks in `Users/user/go/src/github.com/org/project-name`.

Comment: No clue what you refer to by "making up" names and lying about their locations? The files are there in the correct path in relation to the `GOPATH`, and it's exported as one is supposed to..?

Comment: "My project exists under: Users\user\go\src\project-name" This is wrong. Why did you deviate from what "How to Write Go Code" tells you. Place your project under $GOPATH/github.com/org/project-name. Stop fighting the tooling.

Comment: No need to be hostile and rude... I was simply asking for advice and help :)

Comment: "My package is called foo, so I'll just call it github.com/randomstuff/foo" is what I mean by "making up names".  Call your package by it's actual name--don't just make stuff up.

Comment: Great stuff, thanks. By the way, the attitude of you and @Volker is likely why SO is becoming seemingly hostile. You could just make your point without being rude about it - I'm just trying to learn, really. You actively deter people from asking questions by being rude just to cement your points.. :)

Comment: I cannot speak for Volker, but for myself, I come to SO because I believe in helping people become better coders. Spoon-feeding answers rarely does that. My goal is never to be rude, but sometimes answering an obvious question with an obvious answer, inevitably, seems rude. I blame the impersonal medium. In this particular case, every detail for the answer is contained in the question. It's further clear that you've read the documentation, yet continue to fight the tools. If Volker and I can point that out in a "less rude" way, I welcome your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

A package has two things:

1. A *name*. This is set by the `package thename` declaration.
2. An *import* *path*. This path is relative to $GOPATH/src.

You should (no arguing here) do the following:

1. The *name* and the last component of the *import* *path* should match. E.g. if the import path is "sun/moon/stars" than the package name is "stars". (A lot of people get this wrong and either call the package or the folder stuff like go-stars. Don't do that.)
2. Your folder structure on disk must match the import paths of your package. If the import path of your package is "whatever/random/noise" you *must* place it under $GOPATH/src/whatever/random/noise. Or put the other way around: If you code is in $GOPATH/src/ill/do/it/my/own/way then the import path of package "way" is "ill/do/it/my/own/way".
3. If you want you package to be `go get`able place it on a known code hosting and import it by the full import path. Restrictions on import path might apply. Place code of package "foo" under $GOPATH/src/github.com/you/repo/whatever/deep/folder/structure/foo and import it with `import "github.com/you/repo/whatever/deep/folder/structure/foo"`
4. All your paths and package names should be all lowercase.

It boils down to: Do not do anything fancy, keep it natural. Import path and folder structure *must* match.